# Ao disparar um Trigger de Update, um dos campos só atualiza após um segundo Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, trigger

Criei um trigger para poder informar a multa sobre atraso de devolução de filmes alugados, porém, ao disparar o trigger uma vez (dando um UPDATE), o campo "MultaTotal" não atualiza (apenas ele). Mas ao dispara o trigger uma segunda vez, o campo informado é atualizado normalmente. Alguém sabe como resolver, se é um problema, ou se é algo normal para o caso apresentado?

TRIGGER:

```
instead of update
as

declare @CodLoc int
declare @FilmeLoc int
declare @Multa float

select @CodLoc = CodLoc, @FilmeLoc = FilmeLoc, @Multa = Atraso * MultaDia

from inserted

UPDATE Locacao
SET Atraso = DATEDIFF(DAY,DtAluguel, GETDATE()), DtEntrega = GETDATE(), Situacao = 'Devolvido', MultaDia = (SELECT MultaDia FROM Filmes WHERE CodFilme = @FilmeLoc), MultaTotal = @Multa
where CodLoc = @CodLoc

update Filmes
set Disponibilidade = 'Disponivel'
where CodFilme = @FilmeLoc
```

E a seguinte tabela:

```
TABLE Locacao
(
CodLoc INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
ClienteLoc INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Clientes(CodCliente) NOT NULL,
FilmeLoc INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Filmes(CodFilme) NOT NULL,
DtAluguel DATE,
DtParaEntrega DATE,
DtEntrega DATE,
Atraso INT,
Situacao VARCHAR(9), /* Alugado ou Devolvido */
MultaDia FLOAT,
MultaTotal FLOAT,
PRIMARY KEY (CodLoc)
)
```

Porém, quando faço um Update, o campo MultaTotal só atualiza após um segundo Update:

Exemplo:

```
    insert into Locacao (ClienteLoc, FilmeLoc, DtAluguel, DtParaEntrega, Situacao, MultaDia)
    values (2, 1, GETDATE(), DATEADD(DAY, 3, GETDATE()), 'Alugado', 2)
    SELECT * FROM Locacao

CodLoc      ClienteLoc  FilmeLoc    DtAluguel  DtParaEntrega DtEntrega  Atraso      Situacao  MultaDia               MultaTotal
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ------------- ---------- ----------- --------- ---------------------- ----------------------
3           2           1           2018-12-09 2018-12-12    NULL       NULL        Alugado   2                      NULL
```

Update 1:

```
update Locacao
set DtEntrega = GETDATE()
where CodLoc = 3
SELECT * FROM Locacao

CodLoc      ClienteLoc  FilmeLoc    DtAluguel  DtParaEntrega DtEntrega  Atraso      Situacao  MultaDia               MultaTotal
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ------------- ---------- ----------- --------- ---------------------- ----------------------
3           2           1           2018-12-09 2018-12-12    2018-12-09 0           Devolvido 2                      NULL
```

Update 2:

```
update Locacao
set DtEntrega = GETDATE()
where CodLoc = 3
SELECT * FROM Locacao

CodLoc      ClienteLoc  FilmeLoc    DtAluguel  DtParaEntrega DtEntrega  Atraso      Situacao  MultaDia               MultaTotal
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ------------- ---------- ----------- --------- ---------------------- ----------------------
3           2           1           2018-12-09 2018-12-12    2018-12-09 0           Devolvido 2                       0
```

Answer (score 4):

Procedimentos de gatilho (*trigger*) são mais difíceis de serem programados em SQL Server do que em outros gerenciadores, por causa do esquema que é utilizado internamente no SQL Server.

De forma geral, quando se programa procedimento de gatilho para eventos UPDATE é necessário ter em mente de que ele será acionado para toda e qualquer alteração em qualquer coluna(s) da tabela. Por exemplo, se houver alteração na data prevista de devolução (correção de entrada errada), o procedimento de gatilho que criou trata a alteração como se fosse devolução! Percebeu a arapuca em que caiu?

Em tempo, não é confiável utilizar colunas do tipo de dados `float` para armazenar valores monetários; sugiro que altere a declaração das colunas `MultaDia` e `MultaTotal` para o tipo de dados `numeric`.

Há vários pontos a serem revistos no procedimento de gatilho.

**(1)** O valor da multa é calculado sem que o atraso em dias tenha sido calculado:

```
@Multa = Atraso * MultaDia
```

Como `Atraso` está sem informação (NULL) na primeira execução, então o valor de `@Multa` será NULL. Aliás, este é o motivo do funcionamento irregular que percebeu.

**(2)** O cálculo de atraso deve considerar o atraso em relação à data prevista de entrega e não em relação à data de locação.

```
Atraso = DATEDIFF(DAY,DtAluguel, GETDATE())
```

Além disso, somente deve ser calculado se realmente estiver em atraso. Caso contrário, o valor ficará negativo se o filme for devolvido antes do prazo...

**(3)** No momento da inclusão o valor da multa por dia foi registrado; então não faz sentido obter novamente esse valor no momento da atualização:

```
MultaDia = (SELECT MultaDia FROM Filmes WHERE CodFilme = @FilmeLoc)
```

principalmente que o valor total da multa já foi calculado anteriormente:

```
@Multa = Atraso * MultaDia
```

E há outros pontos que necessitam de revisão. Aliás, o procedimento teria que ser reescrito *do zero*. Entretanto, sugiro que implemente o cálculo da multa no próprio aplicativo; é bem mais simples.

Inclusive no artigo “[Armadilhas na programação de procedimentos de gatilho (*trigger*)](https://portosql.wordpress.com/artigos/)” são relacionadas algumas das arapucas.